# restify.js route endpoint conflict with parameter

Tags: node.js, express, restify

My code is like below:

1. `server.get('/currency/:code', currency.find);`
2. `server.get('/currency/rates', currency.rate_getall);`

Whenever I try to reach [/rates] endpoint, the server will assume I am passing parameter to '/currency/:code' route. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Ryan

Comment: Try changing the order. That would be a hack. More better solution would be to rethink your API design.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use RegEx and it works so far. However I am curious if there is any other proper and better way to solve it out. Thank you. The RegEx I used is `server.get('/currency/:code((?:^|\W)(rates)(?:$|\W))', currency.find);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can I would consider changing up your rest interface just a little.

```
server.get('/currency/:code', currency.find);
server.get('/currency/rates/:type', currency.rate);
```

That way it solves your initial problem and allows for flexibility in the future if you just want to return a rate for a particular currency.

Inside your `currency.rate` function you could check for either an id or the literal 'all' and return what is appropriate.